# How to enable CORS in WebSphere 7 with Java Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, websphere, cors

```
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com");
```

I only wanted to allow 'https://example.com' to access my Java servlet with POST request. How do I can enable CORS in IBM WebSphere 7.0.0.27

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide specific informations about Websphere 7, but it is not complicated to write a servlet filter, which handles the CORS preflight requests. Here are two resources that explain the protocol:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

The filter needs to do 2 tasks:

1. Recognize if the http request is a CORS preflight request.
2. If it is a CORS preflight request:

   - set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com`
   - set other `Access-Control-*` header

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Why only the preflight, CORS takes POST as not critical request and does not send a pre flight In my mind that should he protected as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFProtector_Project or the CSRF information in General. There is a J2EE filter as well on their page.

You have to build a filter which checks the origin header (if you do it on your own) it is no rocket science, but some browsers do implement the spec differently. Chrome does always set the origin header.

Even with CORS you would still need to protect against the old CSRF attack like auto form submit as this would not set origin header as far as I know.